# basic java bullet animation using Timer

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a basic bullet animation where when the space bar is pressed, a timer goes off incrementing the bullet's y values by 100 roughly every second.  When I press the space bar, however, nothing appears as if the bullet didn't get it's y coordinate.  This all happens inside of a while loop for when the bullet goes off the screen

```
Timer t = new Timer();

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    bullet.x = 100;
    while (bullet.y<400) {
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  
                bullet.y = bullet.y + 100;
            }
        }, 800);
    }
}
```

Comment: use keyblind not awt keyevents.because bullet need  focus to listen awt keyevent.put sout inside keyaction and see it's not get printed

Comment: thanks for the input, don't quite understand though

Comment: 1- Use a Swing Timer, as it triggers it updates within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread; 2- Call repaint to trigger and uodate; 3- Consider using the key bindings API instead of a KeyListener

Answer (score 1):

I put together a basic bullet demonstration.

The bullets (ovals) move from left to right ( x coordinate) at 100 pixels per second.  When you press the space bar, a bullet is fired from x = 20 pixels and a random y coordinate.  The bullets disappear 20 pixels from the right edge of the drawing panel.

[image: Bullet Demonstration]

I used the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to put this demonstration together.  I wrote  2 model classes, 2 view classes, 2 controller classes and one class to start the Java Swing application.

The first class, BulletDemo, starts the Java Swing application.

```
package com.ggl.bullet;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.bullet.model.BulletDemoModel;
import com.ggl.bullet.view.BulletDemoFrame;

public class BulletDemo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new BulletDemoFrame(new BulletDemoModel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BulletDemo());
    }

}
```

19 lines of Swing packed goodness.  This class does 3 things to get the Swing application started.

1. Puts the Swing application on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) with the call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.
2. Instantiates the Bullet Demo Model.
3. Instantiates the Bullet Demo Frame.

Next, we'll look at the BulletDemoModel class.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.model;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BulletDemoModel {

    private int panelWidth = 600;
    private int panelHeight = 300;

    private List<Bullet> bullets;

    public BulletDemoModel() {
        this.bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    }

    public Dimension getPanelDimension() {
        return new Dimension(panelWidth, panelHeight);
    }

    public int getPanelWidth() {
        return panelWidth;
    }

    public int getPanelHeight() {
        return panelHeight;
    }

    public void addBullet(Bullet bullet) {
        this.bullets.add(bullet);
    }

    public void removeBullets() {
        for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!bullets.get(i).onScreen()) {
                bullets.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveBullets(int time) {
        for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
            bullet.moveBullet(time);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
            bullet.draw(g);
        }
    }

}
```

This class keeps the width and height of the drawing panel we'll discuss later.  This class also keeps track of the bullets.  Bullets can be added, moved, and removed.

The draw method is included with the model, because it's easier for objects to draw themselves.  The draw method is executed as a part of the view, so we still have a separation of concerns.

Next, we'll look at the other model class, Bullet.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Bullet {

    private int maxX;

    private Point2D location;

    public Bullet(Point2D location, int maxX) {
        this.location = location;
        this.maxX = maxX;
    }

    public void moveBullet(int time) {
        double x = this.location.getX();
        double y = this.location.getY();

        x += 100D * (double) time / 6000D;

        this.location.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public boolean onScreen() {
        int x = (int) Math.round(this.location.getX());
        return x < maxX; 
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int x = (int) Math.round(this.location.getX());
        int y = (int) Math.round(this.location.getY());

        if (onScreen()) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

This class encapsulates the fields and methods pertaining to a bullet.

Next, we'll look at the view classes, starting with the BulletDemoFrame class.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.view;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import com.ggl.bullet.controller.BulletRunnable;
import com.ggl.bullet.controller.ShootBulletAction;
import com.ggl.bullet.model.BulletDemoModel;

public class BulletDemoFrame {

    private BulletDemoModel model;

    private BulletRunnable bulletRunnable;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    public BulletDemoFrame(BulletDemoModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Bullet Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        setKeyBindings();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        this.bulletRunnable = new BulletRunnable(this, model);
        new Thread(bulletRunnable).start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        InputMap inputMap = drawingPanel
                .getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "shoot bullet");

        inputMap = drawingPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "shoot bullet");

        drawingPanel.getActionMap().put("shoot bullet", 
                new ShootBulletAction(model));
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        bulletRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void repaintDrawingPanel() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

}
```

Notice how we use a JFrame.  We do not extend a Swing component, or any Java class, unless we want to override one of the class methods.

The createPartControl method is mostly boilerplate, applicable to almost any Swing application.

The setKeyBindings method is where we set the space bar to the ShootBulletAction class, which we'll discuss later.

The windowListener and the exitProcedure allow us to stop the bullet thread before we exit.

Next, we'll look at the DrawingPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.view;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.bullet.model.BulletDemoModel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6510468728309920700L;

    private BulletDemoModel model;

    public DrawingPanel(BulletDemoModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.setPreferredSize(model.getPanelDimension());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        model.draw(g);
    }

}
```

There's not much here, since all the drawing code is in the model.

We extend JPanel so we can override the paintComponent method.  In the paintComponent method, we call the super method, then we redraw the entire panel.  Doing this fast enough creates the illusion of animation.

Next, we'll look at the controller classes.  We'll look at the ShootBulletAction class first.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

import com.ggl.bullet.model.Bullet;
import com.ggl.bullet.model.BulletDemoModel;

public class ShootBulletAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5783106403902351044L;

    private BulletDemoModel model;

    private Random random;

    public ShootBulletAction(BulletDemoModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        double x = 20D;
        double y = (double) random.nextInt(model.getPanelHeight() - 20) + 10; 
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet(new Point2D.Double(x, y), 
                model.getPanelWidth() - 20);
        model.addBullet(bullet);
    }       

}
```

This class creates a bullet every time the space bar is pressed.

Finally, we'll look at the BulletRunnable class.

```
package com.ggl.bullet.controller;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.bullet.model.BulletDemoModel;
import com.ggl.bullet.view.BulletDemoFrame;

public class BulletRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running;

    private long sleepTime = 100L;

    private BulletDemoFrame frame;

    private BulletDemoModel model;

    public BulletRunnable(BulletDemoFrame frame, BulletDemoModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        while (running) {
            model.moveBullets((int) sleepTime);
            redraw();
            sleep();
        }
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void redraw() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.repaintDrawingPanel();
            }
        });
    }

    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

}
```

This class is the basic update model, draw model, sleep loop that controls most animation.

We're running at 10 frames per second, which is a bit choppy.  You can sleep for less time and run more frames per second if you want.

I know this has been a long answer, but this is how you do basic animation in Swing.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: I added a download link for the program: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01247857767704445193